# Two Jackson ObjectMapper generate different serializations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson2

I have two ObjectMapper instances of Jackson. (Using v2.8.3)

The first one is instantiated as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

The other one is autowired from the Spring Boot context via `@Autowired`.

Both have the same visibility configurations like this:

[image]

But they produce different serializations for the same object. The differences I realized are as follows:

- Order of the serialized fields
- Serialization of protected transient fields. (The autowired instance does not serialize them at all.)
- Case differences in the serialized fields i.e. the former generates "monitoringUserID" while the latter "MonitoringUserID".

What I want is that the autowired mapper would also serialize the protected transient fields.

I'd also be glad if you tell me the reasons on the other differences in both serializations.

A simplified version of an example class being serialized:

```
public class ClauseType implements Serializable {
    protected transient List<ClauseTypeNoteItem> noteItems;

    public ClauseType() {
    }

    public List<ClauseTypeNoteItem> getNoteItems() {
        ...
    }

    public void setNoteItems(List<ClauseTypeNoteItem> value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Complete ClauseType class: https://pastebin.com/m3h1hesn

Complete ClauseTypeNoteItem class: https://pastebin.com/dmphNV4e

**Edit:**
I realized that both instances had difference mapper features. According to the docs, after enabling the `DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` featured of the autowired instance, they had the same mapper features represented as 1068991. However the differences are still there. I also realized that the autowired mapper has two registered modules: `org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponentModule` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule`. I'm not sure whether the second module has an effect on the results I'm getting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show class you are serializing. Because for me both of them serialize only public fields.

Comment: @RuslanAkhundov just updated the post

Comment: Spring Boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) make it clear that the default Jackson mapper provided by Spring has some customized properties out of the box.  Can you narrow it down to those differences?

Comment: Yes, the DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION feature was different in both settings. But I still have the different results even after enabling it. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that Spring injects a `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` coming from `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` maven dependency. During the instantiations of `BeanDescription`s, the Jaxb introspector overrides the visibility checker settings that I provided. So, as a solution I will inject a new `ObjectMapper` bean and mark it as `@Primary`.

If you think of any other better solution, let me know

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot the Jackson `ObjectMapper` is build and customised by `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` object. The main source of configuration are the `spring.jackson.*` properties as explained in the docs:

- [74.3 Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)
- [Appendix A. Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)